# mypy error when adding a list of list of ints with a list of list of floats

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a python class that looks as following:

```
from typing import List
import numpy as np

class TestClass():

    def test(self) -> np.ndarray:
        a: List[List[float]] = [[1, 1.3, 0.5]]
        return np.array([[0,0,0]]+a)
```

in practice, this function should simply return [[0,0,0],[1, 1.3, 0.5]]. However, mypy returns the error message `Unsupported operand types for + ("List[List[int]]" and "List[List[float]]")`. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: Please provide your mypy code so others can help

Comment: So, `float` and `int` should have special-case "ducktype compatibility", but I bet this is not squaring with the invariance of lists.

Comment: @manaclan what do you mean by mypy code? I just save the abovementioned snipped in a file and then call mypy <file> on my wsl. My mypy.ini only contains a few ignore missing imports statements. Do you need any more information?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Theoretically I should be able to concatenate lists of any types since the contents don't need to be related. Do you have an idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: @hhhh no, **absolutely not**. What do you mean theoretically? A list of type `List[A]` can only be concatenated with lists of type `List[A]`. Here, you can just use `[[0.,0.,0.]]+a`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay, so the only solution here would be to define the [0,0,0] list beforehand as a list of floats? Is there a better way to do it than in a seperate line?

Comment: I just showed you: `[[0.,0.,0.]]+a`